# Transpose Spark DataFrame with Scala

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame which I want to transpose. I am using Spark and Scala. I have seen many post, but none of them answer my question.

I tried using pivot. But that use group and aggregate function which return single value in row. Which is not my expected result.

Below is Spark Dataframe which I have

```
a   b   c   d
x   1   10  555
y   2   20  556
z   3   30  557
l   4   40  558
x   5   50  559
m   6   60  560
y   7   70  561
```

I want to make column "a" value as new columns and value of "d" column as rows.

Below is the output which I am expecting

```
x   y   z      l     m
555 556 557   558    560
559 561 null  null   null
```

It should be if I want to consider two or more column value as rows in output. Example if I want value of column "c" and "d" as rows in output.

I am not able to get the solution. I tried alot.

Please help me how to do transpose in spark and scala like this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you write what you have already tried? tried a lot is not quantitative statement. So far I don't see any code snippets of what you have tried already ..

Comment: I had answered something similar in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628129/how-to-get-transpose-of-dynamic-dataset-for-below-sample-input-using-spark-and-j/55642286?noredirect=1#comment99392757_55642286 . you can modify it to cater to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a Java List of the rows of the data frame
`List<Row> rows = df.collectAsList();`
`Map<String, List<Integer>> mapped = rows.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Row::get(0),Collectors.toList(Row::get(3))));`